# Negar una palabra preservando lo que hay antes y después

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo el siguiente string

```
Hola bar mundo
bar mundo
```

Intento ignorar `bar`, pero preservar lo que hay antes y después

**Intenté de las siguientes maneras**

1. **Usar negación por defecto**

```
[^bar]
```

No funcionó, hace match a cada letra exceptuando `bar`, lo que quiero es que obtenga las palabras (Algo como lo que se logra con `[a-z]{1,}`)

2. **Negar la palabra**

```
^(?!.*bar).*$
```

Tampoco funciona, hace *match* a líneas que no tengan `bar`, lo que quiero es obtener todas las líneas y obtener todo lo que está antes y después de `bar`

---

Si tengo el string

```
Hola bar mundo
```

Y uso el último regex

```
^(?!.*bar).*$
```

<sub>(Con flags global y multiline)</sub>

No tengo *matches*, lo que quisiera obtener sería lo siguiente

```
Hola mundo
```

Comment: ¿Usted quiere eliminar un fragmento de la cadena? ¿Está trabajando con algún lenguaje en específico? Le pregunto esto porque, hasta donde sé, las expresiones regulares por sí mismas no modifican una cadena.

Comment: @eniel.rod Uso JS del lado del cliente, lo que intento es excluir una palabra de todos los matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En JavaScript no es posible con pura `RegExp` obtener un string sin una específica palabra, pero sí es posible obtener una lista de palabras sin aquella palabra:

```js
const string = 'Hola bar mundo';
const regexp = /\b(?!bar)\b\S+/g;
const result = string.match(regexp);
console.log(result); 
// [ 'Hola', 'mundo' ]
```

Le recomiendo usar `.replace` para borrar la palabra:

```js
const string = 'Hola bar mundo';
const result = string.replace(/bar /, '');
console.log(result); 
// 'Hola mundo'
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya la respuesta está dada, igual le dejo el ejemplo que estaba desarrollando, que incluye además el tratamiento de los espacios en blanco que pueden resultar del borrado de una palabra.

```js
let x = "Hola bar mundo bar mundo";
// La g indica global, para que no retorne después de la primera coincidencia
// y así reemplace todas las ocurrencias  
x = x.replace(/bar/g, "").replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ");
console.log(x);
```

`.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ")` reemplaza los espacios (espacio, tab, cambio de línea) consecutivos (dos o más) por un espacio.

Comment: Para los curiosos: `.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ")` reemplaza cada espacio doble con un espacio singular, lo que puede permanecer cuando se borre una palabra de un string.  Técnicamente, `\s` significa cualquier espacio en blanco, y `{2,}` significa al menos 2 consecutivos.